# How to sculpt with dyntopo without damaging uv?

Tags: uv, sculpting, dynamic-topology

Is there a way to use dyntopo on an object that already has uv without damaging it's uv map, and if it is not possible
at least make the texture look the same?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to have your "reference" texture while sculpting, it might help to set a background image to your camera (Front depth)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible.  Once the sculpting is finished the model should be retopologized and the UV mapping should be redone for the new topology.

[image]

Comment: Yep, it goes sculpt/model > retopologize > unwrap > texture > animate, in that order